# How to Display Two Columns in one ListBox?

Tags: c#-2.0

Dear Members and Masters
I'm trying to display two columns from MSSQL 2008 Database in one listbox...
Listbox's DisplayMember Property can access only one Member..
So..i want to display two columns in one listbox....
How can i do that?
Please answer me if you know:

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using Winforms you may have a look at [Multi-Column ListBox Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/mclb.aspx)Use this control

Remember always Use Google and search for similar posts.Make google your friend

Comment: if this was answer to your question mark it as answer so that in future people can see it as an answer